# register_on_progress_callback() method of pytube module causing problem

Tags: python, pytube

I am trying to make a downloader with a progress bar for youtube videos using [pytube](https://pypi.org/project/pytube/), but I am stuck on an error.

My code:

```
from pytube import YouTube 

def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining 
    percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    print(percentage_of_completion)

url = "https://www.youtube.com/wat
ch?v=XQZgdHfAAjI&list=PLec973iciX1S0bLNOdmIejMVnUnBWpIwz"

yt_obj = YouTube(url).register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)

stream = yt_obj.streams.filter(progressive=True).get_highest_resolution().download()
size = stream.filesize
print(f"file size is {size}")
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytube_progress.py", line 15, in <module>
    stream = yt_obj.streams.filter(progressive=True).get_highest_resolution().download()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'streams'
```

Interestingly, when I replace this line of code: `yt_obj = YouTube(url).register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)` with `yt_obj = YouTube(url)` every thing works fine, and there are no errors.

Documentation for the `register_on_progress_callback()` function can be found [here](https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.YouTube.register_on_progress_callback).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem in your code is, when the line

```py
yt_obj = YouTube(url).register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)
```

is executed, since the `register_on_progress_callback()` doesn't return anything, the variable `yt_obj` is assigned the value `None`. Then, when you have `yt_obj.streams` later in your code, that triggers the `AttributeError`.

The second problem is with this line:

```py
stream = yt_obj.streams.filter(progressive=True).get_highest_resolution().download()
```

The `download()` function returns a `str`, not a `Stream`.

Here is a working version of your code, with these two problems fixed:

```py
from pytube import YouTube

def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    percentage_of_completion = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    print(percentage_of_completion)

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XQZgdHfAAjI&list=PLec973iciX1S0bLNOdmIejMVnUnBWpIwz"

# Create the YouTube object first
yt_obj = YouTube(url)

# Then register the callback
yt_obj.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)

# Download the video, getting back the file path the video was downloaded to
file_path = yt_obj.streams.filter(progressive=True).get_highest_resolution().download()
print(f"file_path is {file_path}")
```

Answer (score 2):

This would work as well, note you'll just get progress bar once, as 2nd time you run the script you will already have the file downloaded.

```
from pytube.cli import on_progress
from pytube import YouTube

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DkU9WFj8sYo"

print("\n")

try:

    yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
    yt.streams\
    .filter(file_extension='mp4')\
    .get_highest_resolution()\
    .download()

except EOFError as err:
    print(err)

else:
    print("\n====== Done - Check Download Dir =======")
```