# Pytube us of on_progress_callback

Tags: python, pytube

I'm working with the Pytube library. There are some callback functions that I would like to use to update a loading bar. I can't seem to get it to work. Looking at other issues as well it appears to me that the code is correct. I can't identify why progress_callback is never called in any case.

```
def on_progress(self, chunk: bytes, file_handler: BinaryIO, bytes_remaining: int):
    print(' progress:', on_progress)
video = pytube.YouTube( "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ipa0KsyBViA", on_progress_callback=on_progress)
```

I have doubts about the callback parameters, I've seen some that pointed to additional parameters as well.

**EDIT**

Looking at the source code I set the exact same parameters. Unfortunately to no avail, it seems that the function is never called.

Comment: Your shown function is called `on_progress` while you specify a function called `progress_callback` in your `pytube.YouTube` call, which doesnt exist i suppose

Comment: my bad. I edited the code but i did not edited the third line. progress_callback  should be on_progress i changed the names different time to test the code of other users in the community.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the latest version of pytube (11.0.2) produces an error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'` due to the fact that youtube changed something on their end, so even a simple example from the [official docs](https://pytube.io/en/latest/) wouldnt work. Maybe this is the root of your problem. Temporary solution (found via [this github issue](https://github.com/pytube/pytube/issues/1218)):

1. Uninstall pytube, reinstall hotfixed version:

```
pip uninstall pytube
pip install git+https://github.com/glubsy/pytube@nfunc_regex_patch
```

2. Test if pytube works correctly:

```
from pytube import Youtube
YouTube('https://youtu.be/9bZkp7q19f0').streams.first().download()
```

---

#### If that works, move on. If not - look for another solution. It seems that currently there can be changes every day because Youtube changes things.

---

Your described code should work, however it is not doing alot. With the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556050/12892026) i figured that an on_progress callback requires arguments in the order: `stream`, `chunk` and `bytes_remaining`. Also, printing your function will sumply return the reference of a function object without any actual value. However, it should still run, so i figure your problem was probably the points described in 1. and 2., so check if you can download a file first.

3. Functional, complete example:

```
from pytube import YouTube


def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    """Callback function"""
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    pct_completed = bytes_downloaded / total_size * 100
    print(f"Status: {round(pct_completed, 2)} %")


url = "https://youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0"
yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)

out = yt.streams\
    .filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4')\
    .order_by('resolution')\
    .desc()\
    .first()\
    .download()

print(f"Download complete: {out}")
```

Comment: I'm already using that version of pytube. The problem remains. The function is not called and nothing is printed.

Comment: You need to provide a full reproducible example so we can help you further.

Comment: This is the code im using with your function, i have a UI to choose the quality of the video. For based on that i chose which stream i have to use to download. Now im using the 11 one that is 720p 60FPS so should be not a short file. 
```def download_video(ui, url):
    video = pytube.YouTube( url, on_progress_callback=on_progress)
    streams = ui.streams
    out_file = streams[ 11 ].download()
```

Comment: I understand, however i can still not relate. Follow [this guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to create a minimal reproducible example (including your UI classes etc.), otherwise i can not understand the full scope.

Comment: Found the problem, the stream must belong to the same Youtube() object if I save the stream and do not use the same object then the callback will not work because it does not belong to it.