# Tkinter progress bar not updating during task

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using pytube and tkinter to create a GUI for downloading YouTube videos.

```
progressbar=ttk.Progressbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
progressbar.place(x=175, y=200, anchor="center"), 

yt.register_on_progress_callback(progress)
window.update_idletasks()
yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download(filepath)

def progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    total_size = stream.filesize
    bytes_downloaded = total_size - bytes_remaining
    progress = round((bytes_downloaded / total_size) * 100, 2)
    progressbar['value']=progress
    window.update_idletasks()
```

The progress bar does not update. The first solution I found was to use update_idletasks() to refresh the progress bar, but I've only found examples that use this statement in a loop. I'm trying to update the progress bar while a big, long download function is executing (the windows freezes up and gives "not responding" until the download is complete. I felt like the register_on_progress_callback should have done the job, but apparently not.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554878/register-on-progress-callback-method-of-pytube-module-causing-problem    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554878/register-on-progress-callback-method-of-pytube-module-causing-problem

Comment: Please post your question if there are no duplicates or related questions that may help you to solve your problem. Check the above 2 links and check if they help.

Comment: The solution linked, when run, only outputs "100" when the program finishes. Similarly in my case, the window is "not responding" until the video download finishes and the green bar fills instantly. Using the linked solution as an example, I want the progress to print at regular intervals, say twice a second, instead of simply "100" at the end.