# How the pytube's callbacks: on_download_progress and on_download_complete, are used. I am getting an error while using them

Tags: python, youtube-api, pytube

```
from pytube import YouTube
def download(link):
youtube_Ob = YouTube(link,on_download_progress)
youtube_Ob = youtube_Ob.streams.get_highest_resolution()
try:
youtube_Ob.download()
except:
print("An error occured!")
print("YO! Download Successful")

link = input("Enter the link here: ")
download(link)
```

There is no documentation regarding the the callback `on_download_progress`

I tried many ways like:

```
youtube_Ob.register_on_progress_callback(on_progress)
```

but did not work rather it broke the whole script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [register\_on\_progress\_callback() method of pytube module causing problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65554878/register-on-progress-callback-method-of-pytube-module-causing-problem)